# Overwrite toString for specific function

Tags: javascript, overloading

**Look edits below!**
I am currently looking for a way to overload the `toString` method of **one specific function that is generated dynamically** (returned by function). I know I can overload the `toString` function of `Function.prototype`, but this will overload *all* `toString` functions of *all* functions, I want to avoid this.

My example function:

```
var obj = {
    callme: function() {
        return function() {
            // Dynamically fetch correct string from translations map
            return "call me, maybe"; 
        }
    }
}
// Binding callme to func, allowing easier access
var func = obj.callme.bind(obj); 
console.log(func, func())
```

So far I have tried to just treat the function like a regular JavaScript object.

```
func.toString = function() {
    return this();
}
```

This results in the `Function.prototype.toString` still being called instead of `func.toString`.

Trying to access the `func.prototype` is not possible, the `prototype` property is undefined since it is a function not an object.
Overwriting `toString` of `Function.prototype` is not an option, changing `func` to an object is also not possible since it might brake compatibility with older parts of the code.

**Edit:** The attempts made above are obviously not working since I am overwriting the `toString` of the function `func` and not the `toString` of the returned function. Now a better question: Is there an elegant way to overwrite the `toString` of all functions that are returned by `func` so that they "share" the same `toString`.
(Means I don't have to specify the `toString` for every returned function.)

Comment: Strange. I was going to suggest `func.soString = `...

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it doesn't work? It seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/AwDbm/

Comment: So you are saying you can not override `func.prototype.toString = function(){}`?

Comment: Sorry, it did a small error when rewriting the code to be easier. I overlooked that the return of `callme` actually is a function. This is related to i18n. I will explain in the question. I will rewrite the question entirely. Thanks for the fast response.

Comment: `toString` should return a `String`. Guess why? :-)

Comment: @JanDvorak, In the current snippets given in the question, it does...

Comment: @Kiyura quoting clentfort's comment: "I overlooked that the return of callme actually is a function". In that case, `return this()` returns a function.

Comment: I assume that the custom `toString` is called, and because it doesn't return a `String`, its return value is discarded and the native `toString` implementation is used instead.

Comment: "overwrite the `toString` of all functions that are returned by `func`" - returned by `func`, or created by `func`? Many functions could return the same function, but only one created it.

Comment: Uh, you can return anything you want to: http://jsfiddle.net/AwDbm/2/ If you assign toString, the native implementation will never be called implicitly, Javascript doesn't work that way. It will do a prototype lookup if the property doesn't exist.

Comment: In both cases, `func` itself can be modified to assign it's returnee's `toString`.

Comment: @Kiyura `func.toString = function() {return func}; console.log(func.toString)` results in a `TypeError` being logged.

Comment: @Kiyura so, toString may in fact return anything at all (good catch), but still *shouldn't* :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define `toString` on the returned function in `callme` by storing it in a variable before returning it:

```
var obj = {
  callme: function (){
    function toString(){
      return this();
    }

    var f = function (){
      // Dynamically fetch correct string from translations map
      return "call me, maybe"; 
    };

    f.toString = toString;

    return f;
  }
};

var func = obj.callme.bind(obj);
console.log(func);                //=> [Function]
console.log(func());              //=> { [Function] toString: [Function: toString] }
console.log(func().toString());   //=> 'call me, maybe'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a custom value couldn't you just write a method for that instead of trying to overwrite the toString prototype.

Otherwise if you need to change it for all you can do something like:

```
String.prototype.toString = function() {return this+"test";}
```